# How to avoid TopoJSON memory errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis, topojson

I'm attempting to create a TopoJSON file of school districts in the United States.  I've laid out my workflow as follows:

1. Download and unzip individual TIGER shape files from the Census Bureau (24 ESD, 19 SSD, 56 USD)
2. Batch merge these 99 files together with ogr2ogr
3. Convert merged shapefile to GeoJSON
4. Convert GeoJSON to TopoJSON (ideally I would add state boundaries to the file here as well)

Step 4 is what is causing me problems, I am using the following batch script:

```
call topojson ^
    -o SDs11_Topo.json ^
    -p NAME ^
    --simplify-proportion .1 ^
    --id-property GEOID ^
    -- ^
    ESDs11.json ^
    SSDs11.json ^
    USDs11.json
pause
```

But I am presented with the following fatal memory error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_0 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

This has left me at a bit of a loss on how to continue, I would appreciate if someone could advise on a better workflow or ways to better manage memory when converting to topojson.  Thank you.

Comment: How large are those input GeoJSON files? If they are anything near ~1GB, you must use shapefile input rather than GeoJSON, since shapefiles are more compact and can be streamed. (Node.js has a maximum buffer size of 1GB, which makes it difficult to parse JSON files larger than that.) You can also increase the amount of memory available using `node --max-old-space-size=XXXX bin/topojson`, where XXXX is a large number of megabytes.

Comment: Thanks, using the shapefiles as inputs seems to have solved this issue (the json files were 365, 39, and 18 MB files)  Unfortunately, I am now presented with a different error: `ReferenceError: distance is not defined`, I will create a separate question for this

Comment: subsequent question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/16364671/1332731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `node --max_old_space_size=999 topojson.js ...` to increase the memory available to node.js.

If you're using node.js binaries, you'll want the 64-bit binaries. The 32-bit ones are restricted to 1GB. https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=847

Comment: Thanks, while I was able to avoid the memory error by using the shapefiles as inputs rather than the GeoJSON files, I will accept this answer since it will likely be more useful in other, more resource intensive applications