# How to troubleshoot topojson error: distance is not defined

Tags: javascript, gis, topojson

I'm attempting to create a TopoJSON file of school districts in the United States.  I have a set of three shapefiles that I am attempting to combine into a single topojson file, using the following batch script:

```
call topojson ^
    -o SDs11_Topo.json ^
    -p NAME ^
    --simplify-proportion .1 ^
    --id-property GEOID ^
    -- ^
    ESDs11.shp ^
    SSDs11.shp ^
    USDs11.shp
```

After some time running (as in, not immediately) - I am presented with the following output, and error message:

```
coordinate system: spherical
quantization: maximum error 0.00m (0.00°)

...\npm\node_modules\topojson\lib\topojson\spherical.js:13
  var a = distance(t[0], t[1]),
          ^
ReferenceError: distance is not defined
at ...
```

In case it helps, I have placed the source shapefiles I am using at http://jsl6906.net/D3/SDs/

Any help on how to troubleshoot this error would be appreciated

Comment: Are you running v.1.0.0? Line numbers look different in the current codebase...

Comment: This seems to have been the problem, it I was somehow running v0.0.34,  I tried running `npm update topojson` but this did not seem to help, but after just re-installing using `npm install -g topojson` my version is now 1.0.0.  Will be  testing script with this new installation - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per @nrabinowitz comment above, this error was caused by not running the latest version of topojson. Using `topojson` with no arguments will return the installed version of the library.